# How to add several blank ggplots to the list?

Tags: r, list, loops, ggplot2

Let's say we want to plot some ggplot combined with three empty plots. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
lst <- list(ggplot() + aes(1:10, 1:10) + geom_line())
for (i in 1:3) {
  lst[[i+1]] <- ggplot() +
    theme_void()
}
patchwork::wrap_plots(lst)
```

[image]

As you can see in my code, I assigned to the list by

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  lst[[i+1]] <- ggplot() +
    theme_void()
}
```

and my question is - is there any possiblity to add those three plots but without loop ? I tried some lpply but it lead me to nothing

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
plot1 <- ggplot() + aes(1:10, 1:10) + geom_line()
lst <- c(list(plot1), rep(list(ggplot() + theme_void()), 2))
```

Comment: Is it really working for you ? I get: `"Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"`

Comment: Should probably be `rep(ggplot() + theme_void(), 2)`

Comment: Try this: `lst <- c(list(plot1), rep(list(ggplot() + theme_void()), 2))`

Comment: Wow that worked. You can add this as answer so that I can accept it

Comment: I have corrected the answer based on the comment from @teunbrand

Answer (score 1):

The cheeky solution:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
p <- ggplot() + aes(1:10, 1:10) + geom_line()

wrap_plots(p, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

<sub>P.S. I personally prefer using plot_spacer() rather than theme_void. [Plots with theme_void can have weird behaviour...](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork/issues/237)</sub>